# Print prints the right value but the appends different value to list

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking

I am trying to code the solution to a backtracking problem online.

I face a very weird problem with the code.

The print statement seems to be printing the exact array that I want, but a different one gets appended to the list when the two lines are consecutive

```
class Solution:
    def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        def backtrack(index):
            if index==len(nums):
                print(nums)
                permutations.append(nums)
            else:
                for i in range(index,len(nums)):
                    temp = nums[index]
                    nums[index] = nums[i]
                    nums[i] = temp
                    backtrack(index+1)
                    temp = nums[index]
                    nums[index] = nums[i]
                    nums[i] = temp
        permutations = []

        backtrack(0)
        return permutations
```

The expected output is shown below 
the print statement prints

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
```

But the value I see in the permutations array is

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

which is extremely weird. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Have you tried using the permutations method from itertools? https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: That's not the questions. I know I can do it using that method - but I dont understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: Without seeing how you are calling your method it's hard to comment. The issue you're having is almost certainly down to you referencing and reusing the same list again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `permutations.append(nums)`, you're not appending a *copy* of `nums` -- you're appending a reference to the actual `nums` object.  This means if `nums` ever changes, all of the references change too, because they're all *the same object*.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured that in python changing one list automatically changes another. 
So when I try to do permutations.append(nums) and then change nums, permutations gets modified too.

So the solution for this would be permutations.append(list(nums)).

Answer (score -1):

The code reuses the same list `nums` for all permutations. Therefore all elements in `permutations` point to the same list and are the same.